# Most efficient way to merge lists where the final values are the max from each list maintaining position

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, performance

What's the most efficient way to merge these lists into one single list where the final values are the max from each list maintaining position?  Right now I'm doing a brute force iteration over all of the lists and setting the max value in the final list.  It works but it's not very efficient since my data sets are massive.  Any ideas on how to make this more efficient?

```
graph1 = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 0]]
graph2 = [[5, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 0]]
graph3 = [[2, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0]]
graph4 = [[1, 0, 1], [9, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0]]

graphs = [graph1, graph2, graph3, graph4]

# TODO, what's the most efficient way to merge these lists into one single list where the final values are the max from each list maintaining position?
# desiredResultGraph = [[5, 1, 1], [9, 0, 1], [2, 0, 0]]
```

---

**Updated solution based on Mark Meyer's solution below:**

```
graph = np.ndarray(shape=(4, 3, 3), dtype=float, order='F')
graph[0] = [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 0]]
graph[1] = [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 0]]
graph[2] = [[5, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 0]]
graph[3] = [[2, 1, 0], [9, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0]]

PrintAndLog("graph of type " + str(type(graph)) + " = " + str(graph))

resultGraph = graph.max(axis=0)
PrintAndLog("resultGraph of type " + str(type(resultGraph)) + " = " + str(resultGraph))
```

**Output:**

```
graph of type <class 'numpy.ndarray'> = 
[[[ 0.  0.  1.]
  [ 1.  0.  1.]
  [ 2.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.  1.]
  [ 1.  0.  1.]
  [ 2.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 5.  0.  0.]
  [ 1.  0.  1.]
  [ 2.  0.  0.]]

 [[ 2.  1.  0.]
  [ 9.  0.  1.]
  [ 0.  0.  0.]]]
resultGraph of type <class 'numpy.ndarray'> = 
[[ 5.  1.  1.]
 [ 9.  0.  1.]
 [ 2.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: You can do `[[max(i) for i in zip(*v)] for v in zip(*graphs)]` but using `numpy` will be generally faster.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Got it.  So let's say I start with 4 separate numpy arrays instead of 4 separate lists, how can I do this command you suggested merging those numpy arrarys instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are manipulating large sets of numeric data, you will be hard-pressed to beat the performance of Numpy. And it makes things like this easy:

```
import numpy as np

graph1 = [[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 0]]
graph2 = [[5, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [2, 0, 0]]
graph3 = [[2, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0]]
graph4 = [[1, 0, 1], [9, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0]]

np.array([graph1, graph2, graph3, graph4]).max(axis = 0)
```

Result:

```
array([[5, 1, 1],
       [9, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: I like this solution for its elegance.  But I really doubt it's the fastest.  np.array(....) needs to create a new array by copying all of the data from the existing arrays, all to perform a trivial operation.

Comment: I think that's fair @FrankYellin. I suspect if the OP is really working massive data, it will be in their best interest to try to start with numpy arrays from the beginning.

Comment: I'll test this out, and also look at what it will take to convert my python lists to numpy arrays everywhere to make sure I'm not killing my performance.

Comment: @FrankYellin So even if I start with a numpy array instead of a list, if I use np.array() and feed it numpy arrays it will still do the copy (which is inefficient) right?

Comment: @LampShade, if you are starting with a numpy array it would just be `some_array.max(axis = 0)`, which will be very efficient.

Comment: @MarkMeyer in this case, it would be starting with 4 separate numpy arrays though right?  I cannot just call .max on one of them.  In your solution you essentially made an array of 2d arrays then called max on that outmost array.  So it sounds like you're suggesting to make a numpy 3d array and do a `numpy_3d_array.max(axis = 0)`.  Does that sound right?

Comment: @LampShade, yes. This is typical with numpy when you have data like this. So in this example `graph1` would be `some_array[0]`. This allows numpy to store things contiguously, which helps with the speed.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Is there an efficient way to do this with a 2d array of objects instead of a 2d array of numbers?  Let's say the object has two properties, rate and name.  I'd want to do the merging based on the rate property, and i'd later use the name as metadata to go along with the rate.